# when I use in postman I recevie this error No_Oauth_State: State was not sent back

Tags: oauth2, authorization, accesstoken, postman

can you please resolve this issue

when I try to get the new **access token** in the postman i receive this error

No_Oauth_State: State was not sent back

We can’t log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.

No_Oauth_State: State was not sent back[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you edit your answer and add more details.
What are you actually trying to do.

/services/authcallback/Filetoshare  does not look like a valid endpoint.please provide more details.

---

if you need access token for salesforce   from postman   you have to follow oauth flow.

please refer to docs:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5

in postman , in authorization you can select oauth2.  and   click on button get access token.

Auth url will be : https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
Access token url :   https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Client authentication : send client credentials in body.

provide consumer key and secret as per connected app.

Comment: I have edited the question and added more details to it

Comment: please see edited answer

Comment: I still get the error ...when i use the auth url and  Access token url as same you have given... error was :  URL No Longer Exists
You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com.

You may have reached this page after clicking on a direct link into the application. This direct link might be:
• A bookmark to a particular page, such as a report or view
• A link to a particular page in the Custom Links section of your Home Tab, or a Custom Link
• A link to a particular page in your email templates

Comment: Hi Arun,   can you please review  salesforce oauth doc.      https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5